# Extra comma when concatenate JavaScript Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a few `JavaScript` arrays into a CSV file. However, I need to add line break at certain locations. The following code works, but it accidently add `,` as the first element in Row 2 (or say it add `,` since Row 2). I am wondering what caused this? Thanks in advance!

#### current output

```
Chemical, CAS, MW
, water, 00566, 666
```

#### desire output

```
Chemical, CAS, MW
water, 00566, 666
```

#### code

```
var Chem1 = "water"
var CAS1 = "00566"
var MW1 = "666"

var csv_content = []
var csv_content_final = []
csv_content[0] = ["Chemical, CAS, MW"];
var chem_property = [Chem1, CAS1, MW1];
csv_content[1] = chem_property;
for (kkk = 0; kkk < ($(csv_content).size()); kkk++) {
      csv_content_final[kkk] = csv_content[kkk] + '\n';
}

alert(csv_content_final)
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/godhong/6q7qo88w/1/)

Comment: Why are you using `$(csv_content)`? `jQuery` will look for DOM elements matching those strings.

Comment: @Barmar, I am trying to combine a few variables. I do not think $(csv_content) will cause the problem.

Comment: I think `$(csv_content).size()` will be `0`. Also, `.size()` is deprecated, you should use `.length`.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks and I will replace that

Comment: If you want to get the length of `csv_content`, it should just be `csv_content.length`. You don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: Why is `csv_content[0]` just an array of one thing? Shouldn't it be `csv_content[0] = ["Checmical", "CAS", "MW"]`

Comment: What is it that you expect? If you want a table with a header, use a table with a header. Why would you use an array with one element expecting it to serve/fit as a "header" for several elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the `,` is because by definition the CSV format is '**C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues'

A new line is not considered a delimiter, only a comma.

EDIT:

If you REALLY want to not have a comma at the start, this will work:
`console.log(csv_content_final.join(''));`

http://fiddle.jshell.net/L8zdqo4u/

But this is *not* CSV

[image]

Comment: See updated fiddle for illustrations (you need to open the browser's JS debugging console to see the output) - http://fiddle.jshell.net/6q7qo88w/2/

Comment: so there is no way format strings to the way I want?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you've got `for (kkk....` but if you remove the for loop, and rely upon the default join for arrays which uses commas, then you just join the csv_content array with ('\n') as follows...

```
var Chem1 = "water"
var CAS1 = "00566"
var MW1 = "666"

var csv_content = []
var csv_content_final = []
csv_content[0] = ["Chemical, CAS, MW"];
var chem_property = [Chem1, CAS1, MW1];
csv_content[1] = chem_property;

console.log(csv_content.join('\n'));
```

Comment: thanks for your post. the reason I use that for loop is to introduce another array.  I think this can be done through `concat`